# I have the location in the HTML page. How to get the id or any other attributes of the element at that position

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have the location of an object in a web page.
In selenium, we can get the location of an element as shown in the code below.
I want to know how the reverse could be done in python.

```
str = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")

for i in str:

    print(i.location)
```

Comment: You should edit your post in order to indent properly the code snippet

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ (Also, MCVE please, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Java script I got this.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_script('el = document.elementFromPoint(1285, 19); return el')
ele.wrapped_element.get_attribute("class")
```